# how to filter "all rows where column x doesn't contain [0-9]"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm cleaning a dirty directory. A few (just a thousand or so) records have their postcode messed up, either blank or containing other address data. Usually that means city or county.

A Postcode, whether UK, US, or Canada, has at least one digit in it. A city or county or blank field doesn't. So if I want to filter for just the bad-postcode rows, I want: All rows where postcode column has no numeric digits.

Filter allows 'doesn't contain' but only for specific strings, apparently not expressions like [0..9]. So how?

Comment: Those are text filters, not designed for numbers

Comment: You can try `ISNUMBER` if the bad (or good) rows will contain only a single number.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a helper column you can filter on that

If your codes are in column C, you can put

```
=COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},C2))>0
```

In another column and drag it down. All the `TRUE` has a number. Filter for only FALSE.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Extremely similar to [@Raysafarian](https://superuser.com/users/116196/raystafarian)'s answer, but here is an alternative option just in case that is useful to anyone:

```
=COUNT(SEARCH({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}, A1))>0
```

It doesn't matter with numbers obviously, but keep in mind for text that `FIND()` is case sensitive and `SEARCH()` is not.